# What's wrong with my python graphics code?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm trying to make a 9x9 grid of text boxes.  I keep getting errors during the 'entry' section of the grid function. Please help, I am very sad regarding the unfortunate situation I find myself in due to having code that doesn't do what I want.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def window():
    main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
    main_window.geometry("500x500")      
    main_window.wm_title("Sudoku Solver 2000gazillion")
    main_window.mainloop()

def grid():
    knownNumbers = [
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        ]
    for row in range(0,9):
        for col in range(0,9):
            entry = Entry(main_window, textvariable = knownNumbers[row][col])
            entry[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col) 

def goButtonAction():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Horray!", 'Finished product goes here')

def goButton():
    button=Button(main_window, text = "Solve it!", command = goButtonAction )
    button.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan = 9)

def main():
    window()
    grid()
    goButton()

main() #run it up
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 40, in <module> main() #run it up
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 37, in main grid()
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 25, in grid entry = Entry(main_window, textvariable = knownNumbers[row][col])
NameError: global name 'main_window' is not defined
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Could you post the error messages you get, and describe the results you want please?

Comment: What do you want from this script?

Comment: python 2.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 40, in <module>
    main() #run it up
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 37, in main
    grid()
  File "C:/Windows/System32/temp", line 25, in grid
    entry = Entry(main_window, textvariable = knownNumbers[row][col])
NameError: global name 'main_window' is not defined

Comment: the main window opened but it's just blank

Comment: So what exactly about that error is confusing you? It should be clear: the `grid` function doesn't know anything about the `main_window` variable, because you haven't passed it to that function.

Comment: Dont know about other things but 
your error is because you didn't declared the variable `main_window` as `global`. after `def window():` add this `global main_window`.

Comment: @adil please don't recommend bad practices like that.

Comment: Sorry....
the code was is not structured properly so I just thought....
well Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `main_window` variable in the `window()` function. This will restrain usage of this variable to the `window()` function. If you want it to be available everywhere, you could e. g. define it outside of the `window()` function, e. g. like this:

```
# Imports

main_window = Tkinter.tk()

def window():
    main_window.geometry("500x500")
# Rest of your code
```